# C# parsing xml document with LINQ where there are varying number of duplicate elements

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm new to LINQ and XML but I've been able to parse a basic XML file without a problem. However I have gotten to a situation where I have duplicate elements within a descendant and I need all the information from the duplicates. 
My XML looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Catalog>
    <Macros>
        <Page>
            <HLF></HLF>
            <ML>MCP</ML>
            <Name>2</Name>
            <Macro_Name>Pages\Spare_Page.emp</Macro_Name>
        </Page>
        <Window>
            <HLF></HLF>
            <ML>MCP</ML>
            <Name>2</Name>
            <Macro_Name>RAF\MOTOR_MACRO.ema</Macro_Name>
            <Variant>A</Variant>
            <PlaceHolder>
                <ValueSet>1</ValueSet>
            </PlaceHolder>
            <PlaceHolder>
                <ValueSet>2</ValueSet>
            </PlaceHolder>
        </Window>
        <Window>
            <HLF></HLF>
            <ML>MCP</ML>
            <Name>2</Name>
            <Macro_Name>RAF\MOTOR_MACRO.ema</Macro_Name>
            <Variant>A</Variant>
            <PlaceHolder>
                <ValueSet>1</ValueSet>
            </PlaceHolder>
            <PlaceHolder>
                <ValueSet>2</ValueSet>
            </PlaceHolder>
            <PlaceHolder>
                <ValueSet>3</ValueSet>
            </PlaceHolder>
        </Window>       
    </Macros>
</Catalog>
```

As you can see I have 2 different types of macros which I'm able to access individually without a problem. The problem comes when I try to iterate through the window macros and get to the 'PlaceHolder' section.

```
 var WinMacro = from w in xDoc.Descendants("Window")
                   select new
                   {
                       PG_HLF = w.Element("HLF").Value,
                       PG_ML = w.Element("ML").Value,
                       PG_Name = w.Element("Name").Value,
                       MacroName = w.Element("Macro_Name").Value,
                       MacroVariant = w.Element("Variant").Value,
                       Placeholder = w.Element("PlaceHolder"),
                   };
```

How can I access and save all the ValueSets withing each Placeholder of a macro?

Comment: @octavioccl I have since added a layer of complexity I'm hoping you can help with. I thought the answer was the end of it but it now seems I'm doing to need an attribute in the XML that I need to save as well. Each placeholder element will have a "name attribute as well, <Placeholder name="name">. I need to have both values together in an object to be able to reference later. Would it make sense to save them into a dictionary or just save them as an array of Xelements that I can then access later?

Comment: Through trial and error I answered my own question, I changed my select statement to Placeholder = w.Elements("PlaceHolder").Select(e=> new { Name = e.Attribute("name").Value, Value = e.Value }).ToList(),. Now I can easily access Name and Value later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Elements` method to get all  the placeholders and call a `Select` later  to get the values from each of them:

```
//...
Placeholders = w.Elements("PlaceHolder").Select(e=>e.Value).ToList(),
```

If you want to save the result as a list of integers then you could do the following casting:

```
Placeholders = w.Elements("PlaceHolder").Select(e=>(int)e).ToList(),
```

Comment: This was the perfect approach, it'll let me iterate through a simple list for my processing. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use linq:

```
  var xmlStr = File.ReadAllText("fileName.xml");
  var str = XElement.Parse(xmlStr);
  var result = str.Elements("PlaceHolder").Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
```